Uniqueness of function from an integral transform.
Suppose that $f,g$ are positive, non-decreasing, differentiable functions, with $f(0)=g(0)=0$. Further suppose that $f,g$ are such that $c\sqrt{x}\leq f(x),g(x)\leq Cx$ for all large $x$, and such that
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda f(x)-\lambda^2x}dx=\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda g(x)-\lambda^2x}dx \quad \forall\lambda>0.$$
Does it hold that $f(x)=g(x)$ for all positive $x$? I.e. is the mapping of $f$ to the above integral injective.
The injectivity seems to hold for $f$ simple, or polynomial and I was unable to construct a counter example so this may hold in the generality I state above. However I am unsure how to go about proving it.
From the paper "Asymptotic solutions to the Stefan problem with a kinetic condition at the free boundary", this appears as the Laplace transform of initial data for the Stefan problem pde, where $f$ is the free boundary. I am suspicious then that if we consider the inverse Laplace transform of the above, take this as initial data in the Stefan problem then this would lead to f as the unique solution, hence the above map would be injective. This may not necessarily hold, but seems possible to me.

What makes you think the injectivity holds?

From the paper "Asymptotic solutions to the Stefan problem with a kinetic condition at the  free boundary", this appears as the Laplace transform of initial data for the Stefan problem pde, where f is the free boundary. I am suspicious then that if we consider the inverse Laplace transform of the above, take this as initial data in the Stefan problem then this would lead to f as the unique solution, hence the above map would be injective. This may not necessarily hold, but seems possible to me.
